# Issue with the webpack-bundler

Tags: webpack

I am trying to compile all my tsx files which are in a folder using webpack-bundler ins a single bundle.js file. 
my webpack.config.js is as this:

```
var glob = require('glob');
module.exports = {
    entry: toObject(glob.sync('./src/editor/**/*.ts*')),
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/out",
        library:'bundle',
        libraryTarget:'var'
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },

            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },

    // When importing a module whose path matches one of the following, just
    // assume a corresponding global variable exists and use that instead.
    // This is important because it allows us to avoid bundling all of our
    // dependencies, which allows browsers to cache those libraries between builds.

};
function toObject(paths) {
  var ret = {};

  paths.forEach(function(path) {
    // you can define entry names mapped to [name] here
    ret[path.split('/').slice(-1)[0]] = path;
  });

  return ret;
}
```

Now when i am trying to compile it it is giving me the error as

"Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename [bundle].js".
The same error is coming for each and every file.
The files are individual in themselves.

can someone tell me the way of doing it?

Comment: it would be clearer if you share your file structure in the `src` directory

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have multiple `entry` points but they are compiling to a file with the same name - `bundle.js`. Try to replace:

```
output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/out",
        library:'bundle',
        libraryTarget:'var'
    }
```

with

```
output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: __dirname + "/out",
        library:'bundle',
        libraryTarget:'var'
    }
```

That way you'll get a separate bundle for each of your `.ts` files.

**OR**

Specify a single file name for the `entry` point of your app:

```
entry: './src/editor/somefolder/app.ts',
```

Comment: now it is compiling the whole directory in different name but i want to bundle them up in a single file named as bundle.js.Is their anyway so that i can compile the whole directory in a single .js file

Comment: you should pass the name of your app's entry point script to the `entry` property. After that webpack will take care of all the dependencies that this file has references to.

Comment: all files are independent and i have imported inside them whatever is required and there is no file from where i can access all the other files.But now i want them to get bundled up with their output in one file.Is that possible?